# I can't split string into token using StringTokenizer in java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am trying to split string into token using StringTokenizer.

My code is :

```
    String original = "Short stories for kids are adventurous and interesting ways to teach your children about good morals and right conduct.";
    String delimiters = "+-*/(),.? ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(original, delimiters);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String w = st.nextToken();
    System.out.println("tokens are = = = "+w);
    }
```

When i run this code output is :

```
token are = = = Short
token are = = = stories
token are = = = for
token are = = = kids are
token are = = = adventurous
token are = = = and
token are = = = interesting
token are = = = ways
token are = = = to
token are = = = teach
token are = = = your
token are = = = children
token are = = = about
token are = = = good
token are = = = morals
token are = = = and
token are = = = right
token are = = = conduct
```

I am used space `(+-*/(),.? )` as a delimiter.
There is one word called `kids are`. Where i am getting confused output. But it is something socked output...!!!
Actually i believe the output is both word as a separate out by space (delimiter).

Why i am getting this type of output ?

Comment: It should works, are you sure that there is no other whitespace instead of space between `kids` and  `are`?

Comment: I've tried your code, and it works fine. There must be a different whitespace between "kids" and "are"

Comment: I am getting expected output. Which Java version you are using ? 
Also out of curiosity , is the output you have posted from the program? There is a space between '=' and token in your output but your code is System.out.println("tokens are = = ="+w); which wont give any space.

Comment: Hello @MarcinSokolowski, i cant get you. What is difference between space and whitespace ??

Comment: whitespace could be for example tab `\t` or new line character `\n`. Space also belongs to whitespaces. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: Hello @psvm, I am using java version 7.i tried to run 20 times and i getting same output.

Comment: @MarcinSokolowski i got your point but when i run this, i am getting same output which is i mentioned in post.

Comment: run `for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {`
            `System.out.println(original.charAt(i) + " - " + (int) original.charAt(i));`
        `}` and update your question with the output.

Comment: I believe you may have a tab character in your String variable named original.

Comment: @MarcinSokolowski as per your requested code i get this output :

I get code for space between for and kids is 160.Other than that i am getting 32 for space.

Comment: So in your text between `kids` and `are` there is no space (code 32) but something else (160) code. Fix your sentence.

Comment: @MarcinSokolowski , Which character represents 160 ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: Thank you @MarcinSokolowski i got solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Java are you using.

Tried with Java 7 and it seems to print the right output.

http://ideone.com/JSW7Ki

Output in this form:

```
tokens are = = =Short
tokens are = = =stories
tokens are = = =for
tokens are = = =kids
tokens are = = =are
tokens are = = =adventurous
tokens are = = =and
tokens are = = =interesting
tokens are = = =ways
tokens are = = =to
tokens are = = =teach
tokens are = = =your
tokens are = = =children
tokens are = = =about
tokens are = = =good
tokens are = = =morals
tokens are = = =and
tokens are = = =right
tokens are = = =conduct
```

Comment: Hello @gokkk, I am also using java 7.

Comment: same here, String is split just the way gokkk describes it.